# Scannner Input Match Exception

Tags: java, exception, int, java.util.scanner

I'm tyrying to read a integer from a file. I keep getting a a massive Input Mismatch Exception from trying to read from the file. Ive tried everything I know and its not working for me. Ive done this before I don't understand why this time.

```
    Scanner in_read;
    in_read = new Scanner("usercount.txt");

    int temp = in_read.nextInt();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
```

In the file usercount.txt I have a integer of 2 but its not reading. I close the file before I read from it.

```
2
```

Is the content of the file usercount.txt

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at REGISTER$REGISTER_ACTION.actionPerformed(REGISTER.java:343)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Is the error I get when I run the code

Comment: can you post the file content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let the java know that it will read from a file

```
 Scanner in_read;
    in_read = new Scanner(new File("usercount.txt"));

    int temp = in_read.nextInt();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
```

it will require to throw An IO Exception in case that the file is not  exist

**UPDATE**
In case if the file has blank spaces 
do this

```
 Scanner in_read;
        in_read = new Scanner(new File("usercount.txt"));

        int temp = Integer.parseInt(in_read.next().trim());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
```

Comment: post the content of file

Comment: The content of the file is 1st line integer of 2

Comment: @DRodriguez it won't give an error, if that was the case. Edit the post, and give it exactly as it appears in the file.

Comment: That worked for some odd reason when there isn't any spaces . ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thank You

Comment: Please accept this answer in order to help others which are having this problem too

Answer (score 0):

Actually you got `NoSuchElementException` Exception from calling `.nextInt()` method as Java tries to get an **int** value but it doesn't find it, it ***clearly infers that the file content can't be read as an `int`***.

You just need to make sure the scanner has a next element:

```
Scanner in_read;
in_read = new Scanner("usercount.txt");

int temp = 0;

if(in_read.hasNextInt()) temp = in_read.nextInt();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
```

When you write `if(in_read.hasNextInt())` it will always test before trying to read an `int` value, so it won't fire the Exception.

**Edit:**

If you are not sure that the content is an `int`, you can't just call `nextInt()` without checking upon `hasNextInt()`, but you can call `.next()`.

Comment: `int temp=null`  seriously ?

Comment: There is a element there and the file closes before a attempted read. I didn't know why I was getting it but for some reason there is a blank when the program reads it but in the file there isn't.

Comment: @DRodriguez No if the `2` is wrapped between blank spaces there won't be a `nextInt()`, maybe a `.next()` will get a value, but it's not an `int`.

Comment: @chsdk there isn't in any spaces in the file, that's the first thing I checked when I started getting this error. For some reason .trim is working for me. Just trying to get this project due thank you. I will reference this post in the future if I run into this again.

Comment: @DRodriguez If `.trim()` is working it means your text had some white spaces.

Comment: @chsdk I've checked something is adding spaces when the file is read. I don't know where the spaces are coming from. When I review the file after the integer has ben written it doesn't

Comment: See, told you :) That's only what the code and the Exception are reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

```
  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("usercount.txt");
  int temp;

    try {
   Scanner s= new Scanner(fileReader);

 while(s.hasNext()){
          if (s.hasNextInt()) {
        temp = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("int: " + temp);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
             }
           }
        fileReader.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```